# Mostar WebView desde el Menú de Opciones (overflow)

Tags: android, android-studio

No sé cuál de las dos opciones con la que he probado es la correcta, y el problema es que en cualquiera de los dos no me muestra la página web.

Como Opción 1 en el mismo MainActivity.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 WebView mWebView;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView_ayuda);
     mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ayuda.htm");
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.m_ayuda:
            mWebView.reload();
        break;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView_ayuda"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**----- Como Opción 2** desde una clase Fragment (esta igual interesa más para no llenar el MainActivity de tanto código)

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.m_ayuda:
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Ayuda fragment = new Ayuda();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment ).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        break;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Ayuda.java**

```
WebView mWebView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.ayuda, container, false );

mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById( R.id.webView_ayuda);
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ayuda.htm");
return view;

}
```

**ayuda.xml**

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView_ayuda"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Codigo puesto en la pagina web Ayuda.html 
**Ayuda.htm**

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head><title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width" /> 

<style type="text/css"> 
body {
   margin: 5px 15px 5px 5px;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
span.rvts11
{
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #ff0000;
}
span.rvts12
{
}
.rvps3
{
 widows: 2;
 orphans: 2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class=rvps3><span class=rvts11>TEXTO 1:</span></p>
<p class=rvps3>texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto .</span></p>
<p class=rvps3><span class=rvts11>TEXTO 2:</span></p>
<p class=rvps3>texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto .</span></p>
</body></html>
```

Porque no se muestra la página web, Alguien me puede ayudar ?

Comment: Vamos a lo objetivo: no se muestra el contenido de `ayuda.htm`. ¿Dónde tienes guardado ese archivo? ¿Ese archivo tiene contenido realmente? Lo de la opción 1 o la opción 2 entra dentro de respuestas basadas en opiniones. Debes decidir tú cuál de las dos usar en base al contexto de tu app y lo que ésta haga. Prueba a cambiar esto: `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` por esto: **`return true;`**

Comment: Hola A. Cedano, el archivo de la pagina web como pongo en el ejemplo esta en la carpeta **asset**, y la pagina web si que tiene contenido, aunque sea poco para el ejemplo, tiene varias lineas de texto, en cuento a decidirme por cual de las opciones prefiero la opción 2, así que utilizando el código para este ejemplo he cambiado el código que me dices por **return true;** y sigue sin mostrar la pagina.

Comment: Tienes que poner un mensaje con Log en el case para verificar si está entrando en esa parte del código. Es lo mínimo que siempre hay que hacer: depurar.

Comment: Hay varias cosas que pueden impedir la carga, sería bueno agregar que tiene tu archivo ayuda.htm, ¿Podrías agregarlo por favor?

Comment: Lo ejecuto utilizando el Debug marcando unos puntos de interrupción, como puedes ver en la captura llega a leer la clase Fragment Ayuda.java que contiene el codigo para cargar la pagina web https://funkyimg.com/i/2TboF.jpg, He puesto el codigo de la pagina web en el primer post, no puedo separarlo código ayuda.xml porque muestra un mensaje y no me deja poner el código, es la única forma que he visto para poder ponerlo

Answer (score 1):

No debes tener ningún problema al usar la primera opción, solo asegura crear correctamente el directorio /assets y que el nombre del archivo a cargar sea correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si lo anterior es correcto el problema debe ser el contenido del .html, si usas Javascript habilita su ejecución:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

---

Actualización:

de acuerdo a la configuración que muestras te sugiero no usar estas propiedades ya que podrías estar modificando el contenido con un zoom y por esa razón no ves el contenido de tu html.

```
    //mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    //mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
    //mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Comment: Nada Elenasys, he quitado ese código que comentas, que también lo tengo puesto en otra parte de la aplicación para mostrar otra pagina web y se muestra sin problemas, y a pesar de que la pagina no tiene un código raro, he cambiado esa pagina por otra que si se muestra en otra parte de la aplicación, y tampoco llega a mostrarse, y el `mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true )` lo tengo puesto tambien, y la carpeta esta bien creada porque como te comento tengo otras paginas que se muestran sin problemas, pero en otro apartado no en este menu.